# Browser based plug-in to paste screenshots into web apps?

Tags: browser-addons, web-application

I have some web apps at work that don't natively allow the pasting of images (you can add attachments) into text fields, any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

There can be no generic means to do this, due to the way webservers and webapplications use HTTP POST/PUT operations to send data to the server from a page rendered on the client. You cannot mix Binary and Text data as you want. Even if you did accomplish putting the image data into the textbox, when it was called up later, it would be rendered as a blob of binary data, not an image. Images require a binary write to the response stream, so the browser has to know to request the binary data seperately, and to render it as an image based on mime-type rules.

Comment: Do you have any guidance on how I could do it for a particular web app...or rather point a developer in the proper direction as the case may be.

Comment: Well, the application would have to be written to support these operations, by creating a binary post handler of some kind depending on the development framework. the app itself would need to parse the binary string decode binary info (a text input would assume unicode encoding, which is text only), implement specialized storage for the binary data, and a get handler of some kind that can read that data from storage, and deliver it as a binary write on a new response stream with a mime-type that tells your browser what to do with the data. thats assuming you can get windows to paste it as data